# VueJS - changing options of one select based on the selected option of another select input fetched with JSON

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, drop-down-menu, nuxt.js

I am trying to populate the select options dynamically based on other option selected from other select input (parent select) using VueJS / NuxtJS. Select data is loaded from JSON and looks as follows:

```
 [

  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fruits",
    "types": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mango"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Meat",
    "types": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Beef"
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

I have managed to fetch the names eg. Fruits & Meat and display it on the first select (main one) with data returned as lists:

```
<select v-model="list" name="list" required>
    <option v-for="list in lists" id="list" :key="list.lists" :value=list.id>
       {{list.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now, what I need is once the option for example: Fruits is picked I need to change the options from another select input accordingly with the types of the main option picked.

Any help or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh I love NuxtJs